# Ordering results by boolean attribute equals false

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I want write properly query to get the most hated news.
Current query:

```
@most_hated_news = News.joins(:likes).where('likes.like = ?', false).order('likes.like DESC').first
```

Schema of likes table:

```
# Table name: likes
#
#  id        :integer          not null, primary key
#  like      :boolean
#  person_id :integer          not null
#  news_id   :integer          not null
```

I want to get news, that has most likes equal false.
The problem is, that query doesn't care ordering likes with false value and return news with most positive likes. 
It return news with 3 positive(most) likes and 1 negative. I have in database news with 2 negative(most).
How to write correctly?

Comment: Your question is unclear. Please try to rephrase it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would try something like this:

```
@most_hated_news = News.joins(:likes)
                       .where('likes.like = ?', false)
                       .group('news.id')
                       .order('COUNT(likes.id) DESC').first
```